# Turning XML Twitter data into clickable links using preg_replace

Tags: php, xml, twitter, xml-parsing

I'm pretty new to coding and want to try and build a twitter app for my website. With a little help I was able to get all the basics down, but what I'm now struggling with is two things:

1. Turning the Twitter XML data into clickable links
2. Making sure the XML text renders properly (It seems like "" (quotes) from the XML are being rendered improperly (as "â€œ").

I seem to have found the answers on how to fix these two things, but being so new to PHP, I'm not exactly sure how to implement these two fixes to my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Solution I found to problem 1:

```
function twitterify($status) {
$status = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $status);
$status = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $status);
$status = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $status);
$status = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $status);
return $status;
}
```

Solution I found to problem 2 is to use html_entity_decode... but again I'm just not sure how to implement these two solutions into my code.

My code so far:

```
<?php
            $xmldata = 'https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/carmeloanthony.xml';
            $open = fopen($xmldata, 'r');
            $content = stream_get_contents($open);
            fclose($open);
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);

        ?>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <?php

        foreach($xml->status as $status)
        {

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <img src=" <?php echo $status->user->profile_image_url; ?>" /> </td>
            <td><strong> <?php echo $status->user->name; ?></strong> <i>@<?php echo $status->user->screen_name; ?></i> <br /> <?php echo $status->text; ?></td>  
            <td style="width: 40px;"><?php echo date("M j",strtotime($status->created_at)); ?></td>
        </tr>
          <?php
        }

        ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Use the [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Comment: @SaidBakr The <a> tag would be inserted using the preg_replace function anywhere there is a @, #, or http found in the text. (At least thats my understanding of it)

Comment: @Matt Someone else actually recommended that I use DOM as well, the only problem is I have no idea how I would go about doing that. Would I have to scratch what I already have? Do you mind explaining how DOM would be used and maybe providing some code I can use as reference?

Comment: It's too complex to explain here. Read the documentation that I linked you to in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as far as I got...gotta run!  All that needs done is to change the regex to find links that are at the end of the line...or precede a newline

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<?php
    $xmldata = 'https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/carmeloanthony.xml';
    $open = fopen($xmldata, 'r');
    $content = stream_get_contents($open);
    fclose($open);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
?>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <?php
    foreach($xml->status as $status)
    {
    $statusText=$status->text;
    $pattern = '/((www|http:\/\/)[^ ]+) /';
    $replacement = '<a href="\1">\1</a>';
    $statusText = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $statusText);
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <img src="<?php echo $status->user->profile_image_url; ?>" /> </td>
        <td><strong><?php echo $status->user->name; ?></strong> <i>@<?php echo $status->user->screen_name; ?></i> <br /><?php echo $statusText; ?></td>  
        <td style="width: 40px;"><?php echo date("M j",strtotime($status->created_at)); ?></td>
    </tr>
      <?php
    }

    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Based on what you left me I was able to figure it out. Incase you are interested, I edited your code to include what I added to mine.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set encoding. Set encoding utf-8.